# How can I convert a shell script into a Perl script?

Tags: perl, shell

How can I convert a shell script into a Perl script?

I have a 10k line shell script and want to convert it into Perl. Is there any tool is doing that, or is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no simple converter. From Perl FAQ "[How-can-I-convert-my-shell-script-to-perl?](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq8.html#How-can-I-convert-my-shell-script-to-perl?)"

> Learn Perl and rewrite it. Seriously,
>   there's no simple converter. Things
>   that are awkward to do in the shell
>   are easy to do in Perl, and this very
>   awkwardness is what would make a
>   shell->perl converter nigh-on
>   impossible to write. By rewriting it,
>   you'll think about what you're really
>   trying to do, and hopefully will
>   escape the shell's pipeline datastream
>   paradigm, which while convenient for
>   some matters, causes many
>   inefficiencies.

Comment: +1 for giving essentially the same answer as David Dorward but a) with some backup and b) some tact

Answer (score 9):

1. Learn whichever shell language the script is written in
2. Learn Perl
3. Translate the code

Comment: This is actually the best answer possible I'd think.